# javascript assigning variables prior to function being called

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

Edited to add:***********
@melomene did not like my calling roll and rollP arrays. However, they were declared as arrays. I have added the full javascript file below.

---

I have 2 little arrays: roll[] and rollP[]. They only have 2 items each. When the function 'checkDouble6()' is run, the contents of roll are saved into rollP, like this.

```
rollP = roll;
```

This is the only place in the code that the values of roll get assigned to rollP.

Somehow, this is sometimes occuring BEFORE the checkDouble6() function is called, even though this statement is WITHIN the checkDouble6() function.

I have gone crazy with the console.logs trying to figure this out. Anyhoo..

Here are the code blocks for what happens when the player clicks (which causes the virtual dice to roll), the checkDouble6() function, and the function for 'holding.' Holding is when a player decides to keep the current score and allows the next player to take their turn.

For some reason the preemptive variable assignment does NOT happen when the player's first switch. I think that's because the switchPlayer() function reassigns rollP to [0,0]. But after that, every time a player rolls, the variable array rollP gets the values of roll before the checkDouble6() function is called.

```
document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function(){

    if (isGamePlaying){
        //1.Random number is generated
        roll[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        roll[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;

        //2.Display the result
        document.querySelectorAll('.dice').forEach(diceClass=>diceClass.style.display = 'block');
        document.getElementById('dice1').src = 'dice-'+roll[0]+'.png';
        document.getElementById('dice2').src = 'dice-'+roll[1]+'.png';

        console.log('roll before checkDouble6: '+roll);
        console.log('rollP before checkDouble6: '+rollP);
        checkDouble6();
        console.log('roll after checkDouble6: '+roll);
        console.log('rollP after checkDouble6: '+rollP);

        //3.Update the round score IF the rolled number is not a 1
        if( roll[0]!== 1 && roll[1]!==1){
            //Add score
            roundScore += roll[0]+roll[1];
            document.getElementById('current-'+activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;

        }else{
            //Next player's turn.
            roundScore = 0;
            switchPlayer();
        }  
    }
});

function checkDouble6(){
    if (roll[0]===6 &&(roll[1]===6 || rollP[0]===6 || rollP[1]===6)){
        //lose whole global score. Next player's turn.
        scores[activePlayer]=0;
        console.log('roll during checkDouble6: '+roll);
        console.log('roll during checkDouble6: '+rollP);
        switchPlayer();
    } else if (roll[1]===6 &&(rollP[0]===6 || rollP[1]===6)){
        //lose whole global score. Next player's turn.
        scores[activePlayer]=0;
        console.log('roll: '+roll);
        console.log('rollP: '+rollP);
        switchPlayer();
    } else{
        //everything is fine
    }
    rollP = roll;
    console.log('roll at end of checkDouble6 function: '+roll);
    console.log('rollP at end of checkDouble6 function: '+rollP);
};
```

There are so many console.logs because I was trying to figure out how this was happening. And below is the 'hold' function. Again this doesn't happen immediately after the player's turns switch probably because of setting rollp to [0,0].

```
document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (isGamePlaying){
        //Add current score to global score
        scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;

        //Update UI
        document.getElementById('score-'+activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer];

        //Check if player won the game
        if (scores[activePlayer]>=100){
            //they won
            document.getElementById('name-'+activePlayer).textContent = 'WINNER!';
            document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.player-'+activePlayer+'-panel').classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('.player-'+activePlayer+'-panel').classList.add('winner');
            isGamePlaying = false;
        }else{
            //they didn't win. Next player's turn.
            switchPlayer();
        }
    }

});
```

Here's the whole shebang:

```
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, isGamePlaying;
var roll = new Array(2);
var rollP = new Array(2);

initializeGame();

//document.querySelector('#current-0').textContent = dice;
//document.querySelector('#current-'+activePlayer).innerHTML = '<em>'+dice+'</em>';

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function(){
    // This would be an anonymous function

    if (isGamePlaying){
        //1.Random number is generated
        roll[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        roll[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;

        //2.Display the result
        document.querySelectorAll('.dice').forEach(diceClass=>diceClass.style.display = 'block');
        document.getElementById('dice1').src = 'dice-'+roll[0]+'.png';
        document.getElementById('dice2').src = 'dice-'+roll[1]+'.png';

        console.log('roll before checkDouble6: '+roll);
        console.log('rollP before checkDouble6: '+rollP);
        checkDouble6();
        console.log('roll after checkDouble6: '+roll);
        console.log('rollP after checkDouble6: '+rollP);

        //3.Update the round score IF the rolled number is not a 1
        if( roll[0]!== 1 && roll[1]!==1){
            //Add score
            roundScore += roll[0]+roll[1];
            document.getElementById('current-'+activePlayer).textContent = roundScore;

        }else{
            //Next player's turn.
            roundScore = 0;
            switchPlayer();
        }  
    }
});

document.querySelector('.btn-hold').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (isGamePlaying){
        //Add current score to global score
        scores[activePlayer] += roundScore;

        //Update UI
        document.getElementById('score-'+activePlayer).textContent = scores[activePlayer];

        //Check if player won the game
        if (scores[activePlayer]>=100){
            //they won
            document.getElementById('name-'+activePlayer).textContent = 'WINNER!';
            document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.player-'+activePlayer+'-panel').classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('.player-'+activePlayer+'-panel').classList.add('winner');
            isGamePlaying = false;
        }else{
            //they didn't win. Next player's turn.
            switchPlayer();
        }
    }

});

function switchPlayer(){
    // Set round scores to 0
    roundScore = 0;
    roll = [0,0];
    rollP = [0,0];
    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = 0;
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = 0;

    // Toggle the visuals 
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.toggle('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.toggle('active');

    //change active player from one to the other
    console.log('Switch from player-'+activePlayer);
    activePlayer === 1 ? activePlayer = 0 : activePlayer = 1;
    console.log('to player-'+activePlayer);
};

document.querySelector('.btn-new').addEventListener('click', initializeGame);

function initializeGame(){
    roll = [0,0];
    rollP = [0,0];
    roundScore = 0;
    scores = [0,0];
    activePlayer = 0;  

    document.querySelectorAll('.dice').forEach(diceClass => diceClass.style.display = 'none');
    document.getElementById('score-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('score-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-0').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('current-1').textContent = '0';
    document.getElementById('name-0').textContent = 'Player 1';
    document.getElementById('name-1').textContent = 'Player 2';
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('winner');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('winner');
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-1-panel').classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.player-0-panel').classList.add('active');

    isGamePlaying = true;

};

function checkDouble6(){
    if (roll[0]===6 &&(roll[1]===6 || rollP[0]===6 || rollP[1]===6)){
        //lose whole global score. Next player's turn.
        scores[activePlayer]=0;
        console.log('roll during checkDouble6: '+roll);
        console.log('roll during checkDouble6: '+rollP);
        switchPlayer();
    } else if (roll[1]===6 &&(rollP[0]===6 || rollP[1]===6)){
        //lose whole global score. Next player's turn.
        scores[activePlayer]=0;
        console.log('roll: '+roll);
        console.log('rollP: '+rollP);
        switchPlayer();
    } else{
        //everything is fine
    }
    rollP = roll;
    console.log('roll at end of checkDouble6 function: '+roll);
    console.log('rollP at end of checkDouble6 function: '+rollP);
};
```

Comment: My guess is that `rollP = roll;` doesn't do what you think it does. What it *does not do* is copy over the values. What it does is discard whatever `rollP[0]` and `rollP[1]` were, and from now on treat `rollP` and `roll` as the same array, because that's how references / pointers work. If you want to copy the array, you need `rollP = roll.map(i => i);`

Comment: "*I have 2 little arrays: roll[] and rollP[]*" - No, those are two *variables*. We don't know how many arrays you have because you haven't shown the relevant code.

Comment: @ChrisG, thank you. That is helpful.

Comment: @melpomene, I will edit my question to include all of the code. I assume something in there will be relevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `roll = rollP` you are copying reference from rollP to roll, which means roll and rollP will point to same memory location.

e.g. if you push something in roll, it will be exactly same in rollP and vice-versa.

if I get it correctly, all you want to do is `roll[0] = rollP[0]; roll[1] = rollP[1];`

Comment: Yes! That is exactly it. Thank you. I will make the correction.

Comment: That fixed it perfectly.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)